# setInterval in a slideshow

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have a problem with a following script intended for a slideshow. Currently it is static and I'm aiming to include setInterval so the slides will rotate. Can anyone advice something about how to better implement this method here, because I can't find a proper place where to set setInterval.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theImage = $('ul.photos li img');
var theWidth = theImage.width()
//wrap into mother div
$('ul.photos').wrap('<div id="mother" />');                 
//assign height width and overflow hidden to mother
$('#mother').css({
    width: function() {
    return theWidth;
  }, 
    height: function() {
    return theImage.height();
  }, 
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'hidden'      
});
    //get total of image sizes and set as width for ul 
var totalWidth = theImage.length * theWidth;
$('ul.photos').css({
    width: function(){
    return totalWidth;  
}               
});     

$(theImage).each(       
function(intIndex){             
$(this).nextAll('a')
.bind("click", function(){
    if($(this).is(".next")) {
        $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
            "margin-left": (-(intIndex + 1) * theWidth)             
                }, 1000)    
        } else if($(this).is(".previous")){
        $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
            "margin-left": (-(intIndex - 1) * theWidth)             
        }, 1000)    
        } else if($(this).is(".startover")){
        $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
            "margin-left": (0)              
        }, 1000)
}
});//close .bind()                                   
});//close .each()
});
</script>
```

I will be highly grateful for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write the transition code inside the function to repeat.

```
setinterval(function(){
//do something for every 2 seconds
},2000);
```

if u want to introduce delay between the event

```
$(this).nextAll('a').bind(/*your code*/).delay( 800 );
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. 

Well I'm not sure what function to name, because without the defining one the whole script stops working. I'm not quiet savvy with JavaScript and jQuery, so I could have messed something up. Still, how do you expect the resulting code to look like?